# Camera gets stuck on

Tags: raspbian, camera

Using the raspberry pi camera with `raspivid`, I find that sometimes the camera seems to lock up. `raspivid` exits, but the red LED stays on.

Rebooting does not reset the camera (LED still stays on - sometimes the OS doesn't even start). I have to power cycle the pi to get the camera to work again.

What can I try to fix this?

Comment: Interesting.  I haven't dabbled too much with my camera yet, but I haven't run across anything like this.

Comment: I have also encountered this problem.  For me `init 6` hangs after the Pi displays "the system will now restart".  I have to power off/on to restart.  My guess is that the firmware or driver has hung up.  I would like to know how to debug this also.

Comment: My Pi locks up after every couple of executions of Raspivid.  Once or twice the camera LED was stuck on.  Subsequent executions of Raspivid did nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The causes seem to be

1) poor connection of the ribbon cable.

2) power supply - the camera can use quite a lot of extra juice.

I've been able to stream for quite long times now without issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem of the "camera mysteriously getting stuck on" often when calling stock "raspivid" and "raspistill".

I'm running Raspbian Jessie, and had installed and activated the experimental OpenGL support.

After disabling the experimental OpenGL support (with `sudo raspi-config`), my mysterious problems mysteriously went away....

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that after turning off the experimental Open-GL drivers in raspi-config, I was able to take pictures properly.

My best guess is that this is a memory allocation issue.